# Is the meshed metal cage connected to the earth terminal in these embedded power supplies?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, enclosure

The SMPS below has screw terminal mains entry as line, earth and neutral:

[image]

Is its meshed metal cage in general connected to the earth terminal internally? I could check it if I had one but at the moment I don't have such power supply next to me. I also don't see any indication in the datasheets.

Answer (score 0):

yes, but I would not rely on that connection to provide a safety ground to a larger assembly.

Comment: Because in my case two such supplies are mounted on a metal plate. It means the cages ares shorting the earth terminals of the supplies. Since I dont have access to them at the moment, Im just speculating. See my related question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/411211/are-the-ground-wires-and-the-earth-creating-a-loop-in-this-system/411221#411221

Comment: It is not clear from your question or this comment what your concern is.

Comment: @Transistor If the meshed cages of the supplies are at same potential with their earth terminal, since both power supplies are mounted on the same metal surface that means their earths will remain shorted even though I cut the earth wire between their earth terminals. That was the concern.

Comment: you want the case earthed regardless